# wireless is disabled by hardware switch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, Every thing was working perfectly fine.

After an update is installed my wireless network is stoped working. I am using **HP ProBook 4530s**

The network indicator on right top corner is showing **wireless is disabled by hardware switch**

How to fix it and what to provide for analysing the issue.

Please help me its urgent and i have to fix it and work on a task.

Comment: If you're short of time, use a wired connection and get your work done. You shouldn't do upgrades on a production machine like this without some kind of backup. Laptops usually have a switch which allows you to turn off all wireless radios. Check to see if you accidentally turned yours off.

Comment: I currently don't have LAN right now. I just switched on my very old laptop and posting question from there. What information i would provide you to analyse the issue.

Comment: As per your suggestion. I finally find out the very small network button on laptop. Just pressed it and my problem solved. Hurraahhhhhhh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're short of time, use a wired connection and get your work done. You shouldn't do upgrades on a production machine like this without some kind of backup. Laptops usually have a switch which allows you to turn off all wireless radios. Check to see if you accidentally turned yours off.